# Objects in PHP including other objects

Tags: php, object

I think the title is right but please correct me if It is mis-leading.

The problem: I have a class which wants to use the DB class, now instead of having to "global $db;" in every method I wish to use the DB object I want to be able to place the object reference in my class properties.

Still following? OK here goes:

```
class user
{
    private $id = 0;
    private $name = NULL;
    private $password = NULL;
    private $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->load_db();
    }

    private function load_db()
    {
        global $db;
        $this->$db =& $db;
    }
```

I get an error "Object of class db could not be converted to string" which is annoying as I can't figure out how to set the var type in PHP...

Now my question is two fold:

1) How do I fix this.
or
2) Is there a better way of doing it as this feels really "kack-handed".

Thanks in advance,

Dorjan

edit: Just to make sure I'm clear I do not want to make multiple instances of the same DB object. At least I believe this to be a good practice ^,^

Comment: At which line do you get that error?

Comment: I feel so embarrassed. Thanks guys!

Comment: Instead of using `global $db` altogether you might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection  Can be as simple as `public function setDb(PDO $dbObject) { $this->db = db; }`

Comment: AS many of you have given this advice I'll quickly try that.

Comment: Perfect! Now it looks very clean and avoiding the global :D

You guys always make my code that much better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using $this, you only need one dollar sign. So `$this->db`.

Comment: This is the correct answer for 1), but the other answers on dependency injection are good advice for 2).

Comment: Agreed! Thanks for answering my main question!

Answer (score 2):

```
private function load_db()
{
        global $db;
        $this->db =& $db;
}
```

Also if you are using php 5 you dont need to use the `=&` operator because objects are implicitly passed by reference. Secondly, you should inject `$db` into the constructor or fetch it from a Registry object instead of using `global`.

Comment: oh really? = no longer creates a copy but rather points to the original?

Comment: Actually:
Since PHP 5, new returns a reference automatically, so using =& in this context is deprecated and produces an E_STRICT message.

This is on functions and methods not on assigning var's which still need the & to do this...

I'm still unsure if what you say is indeed true as I can't find the officially documentation saying that Objects are implicitly passed by reference.

I'd love to just trust you but I want to make sure :)

Answer (score 2):

You should better do

```
class User
{
    private $id = 0;
    private $name = NULL;
    private $password = NULL;
    private $db;

    function __construct($db=null)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

}
```

Note that you don't put a `$` before variable names if you access properties via `$object->`. That is were the error comes from.

To use a global inside a class method is really bad practice as you somehow tie your class to that global variable. Better pass it as a parameter to the constructor or a method.

Later you can instantiate the class with

```
$user = new User($db)
```

Also note that class names by convention start with a capital letter.

Comment: :) Very clear makes my code that much better, thank you Felix.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$this->db
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject the db instance through the constructor

```
public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yopu'll want to use something called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This is where you "inject" an object into another object to do whatever it is the object does. In this case do database stuff

class user
{
    private $id = 0;
    private $name = NULL;
    private $password = NULL;
    private $db;

```
function __construct($database_object)
{
    $this->load_db();
    $this->$db = $database_object;
}

public function do_db_stuff()
{
    $this->$db->doStuff();
}    

$db = new Mysql() 
$user = new User($db);
$user->do_db_stuff();
```